# Dates on axis with surface plot with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot Treasuries data with a surface plot with the following axis:

```
X=Maturity 
Y=Dates (already in numeric form date2num)
Z=yield
```

I am using the following commands:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm,linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```

How can I display the Y axis as dates?[Here is my plot, I already used date2num](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QB2y.png)

Comment: Have you got a small sample of the data?

Comment: Also, you may want to check out http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#module-matplotlib.dates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matplotlib: Formatting dates on the x-axis in a 3D Bar graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195983/matplotlib-formatting-dates-on-the-x-axis-in-a-3d-bar-graph)