# Plot dates on x,y axes of matplotlib 3d graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, formatting

I have a large Pandas DataFrame that contains three columns: two different dates and one of measurement (floats). I want to plot a 3d figure (eg. trisurf, plot_surface, etc) where the dates are on the x and y axes and measurement is on the z axis. I tried using the suggestions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195983/matplotlib-formatting-dates-on-the-x-axis-in-a-3d-bar-graph), but it isn't helpful.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as dates
import datetime
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['date1'] = pd.date_range(start='2018-01-05', end='2018-04-15', freq='1D')
df['date2'] = pd.date_range(start='2018-01-19', end='2018-04-29', freq='1D')
df['mydata'] = np.sin(2*np.linspace(-1,1,len(df))) # dummy variable

def format_date(x, pos=None):
    return dates.num2date(x).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') #use FuncFormatter to format dates

plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig,rect=[0,0.1,1,1]) #make room for date labels

ax.plot_trisurf(df.date1, df.date2, df.mydata, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0.2)

ax.w_xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(some_dates)) # I want all the dates on my xaxis
ax.w_xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(format_date))
ax.w_yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(some_dates)) 
ax.w_yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(format_date))

for tl in ax.w_xaxis.get_ticklabels(): # re-create what autofmt_xdate but with w_xaxis
    tl.set_ha('right')
    tl.set_rotation(30)  
for tl in ax.w_yaxis.get_ticklabels():
    tl.set_ha('right')
    #tl.set_rotation(30)  

ax.set_xlabel('date1')
ax.set_ylabel('date2')
ax.set_zlabel('mydata')

plt.show()
```

I keep getting the error `RuntimeError: Error in qhull Delaunay triangulation calculation: singular input data (exitcode=2); use python verbose option (-v) to see original qhull error.` What am I doing wrong and how do I resolve it?

Comment: Your data is not structured for a surface plot. https://stackoverflow.com/q/25476344/7758804

Comment: `ax.bar(df.date1, df.date2, df.mydata,  linewidth=0.2)` this works just fine.

Comment: thanks, I'm not sure how to convert my data into a more suitable structure for surface plots (`ax.bar` doesn't work for me, and this type of graph isn't quite what I'm aiming for)